# How to install Multi Machine Cluster in Standalone Service Fabric?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I am going through guide here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-creation-for-windows-server

Section "Step 1B: Create a multi-machine cluster".

I have installed Cluster on one box and trying to use the same json (as per instructions) and trying to install it on another box so that i can have Cluster running on 2 VMs.

I am now getting this error when I run by TestConfig.ps1:

> Previous Fabric installation detected on machine XXX. Please clean the machine.
>
> Previous Fabric installation detected on machine XXX. Please clean the machine.
>
> Data Root node Dev Box1 exists on machine XXX in \XXX\C$\ProgramData\SF\Dev Box1. This is an artifact from a previous installation - please delete the directory corresponding to this node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, take a look on this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-standalone-deployment-preparation#environment-setup). These are the requirements for each cluster node that are need to be met if you want to create the cluster.

The error is pretty obvious. You most likely have already SF installed on the machine. So either you have SF runtime or some uncleaned cluster data there.

Your first try should be running `CleanFabric` powershell script from the SF standalone package on each node. It should clean all SF data (cluster, runtime, registry etc.). Try this and then run `TestConfiguration` script once again. If this does not help, you would have to go to each node and manually delete any SF data that `TestConfiguration` script is complaining about.

Comment: the other box was brand new. the log on the new box was giving out that error which is even though obvious doesnt explain why it is bothered about cluster already existing on the other box

Comment: @BekRaupov Yes, I agree powershell output of these scripts can be confusing. It has been my experience that `DeploymentTraces` folder contains more specific info, check traces there.